# Facebook friend selector with in in a text box

Tags: facebook, user-interface

Can I implement Facebook friend selector with in a text box such that when I enter a name it will auto populate the matching friends name fetched from my Facebook friend list? Is there any facebook plugin which functions like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no plugin like what you described.

You can implement something like that yourself, but in my opinion it's pointless since facebook hasn't provided any api for friends invite other that the [dialogs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/), so if you do implement such a thing yourself, you'll still **have** to open up the fb invite dialog for the user to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FQL to search within a name

Here's an example of how to search for all friends with 'Neal' in their name
`fql?q=SELECT uid, name  FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid1 FROM friend WHERE uid2=me()) AND strpos(name,'Neal') >= 0`

This will return something like

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "uid": 120,
      "name": "Tina McNeal"
    },
    {
      "uid": 121,
      "name": "Rusty Nealy"
    },
    {
      "uid": 123,
      "name": "Neal Armstrong"
    }
  ]
}
```